# List integration as argument (beginner)

Tags: python

I am writing a script in python, but I am a beginner (started yesterday).

Basically, I just create chunks that I fill with ~10 pictures, align them, build the model, and build the texture. Now I have my chunks and I want to align them...

From the [manual](http://downloads.agisoft.ru/pdf/photoscan_python_api.pdf):

> `PhotoScan.alignChunks(chunks, reference, method=’points’, accuracy=’high’, preselection=False)`
>
> Aligns speciﬁed set of chunks.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - chunks (list) – List of chunks to be aligned.
> - reference (Chunk) – Chunk to be used as a reference.
> - method (string) – Alignment method in [’points’, ‘markers’].
> - accuracy (string) – Alignment accuracy in [’high’, ‘medium’, ‘low’].
> - preselection (boolean) – Enables image pair preselection.
>
> Returns Success of operation.
>
> Return type `boolean`

I tried to align the chunks, but the script throws an error at line 26:

> TypeError: expected a list of chunks as an argument

Do you have any idea how I can make it work?

This is my current code:

```python
import PhotoScan
doc = PhotoScan.app.document
main_doc = PhotoScan.app.document
chunk = PhotoScan.Chunk()
proj = PhotoScan.GeoProjection()
proj.init("EPSG::32641")
gc = chunk.ground_control
gc.projection = proj
working_path = "x:\\New_agisoft\\ok\\Optical\\"
for i in range (1,3):
    new_chunk = PhotoScan.Chunk()
    new_chunk.label = str(i)
    loop = i*10 
    loo = (i-1)*10
    doc.chunks.add(new_chunk)
    for j in range (loo,loop):
        file_path = working_path + str(j) + ".jpg"
        new_chunk.photos.add(file_path)
    gc = new_chunk.ground_control
    gc.loadExif()
    gc.apply()
    main_doc.active = len(main_doc.chunks) - 1
    doc.activeChunk.alignPhotos(accuracy="low", preselection="ground control")
    doc.activeChunk.buildModel(quality="lowest", object="height field", geometry="smooth", faces=50000)
    doc.activeChunk.buildTexture(mapping="generic", blending="average", width=2048, height=2048)
PhotoScan.alignChunks(,1,method="points",accuracy='low', preselection=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I have never used this module.*

You're calling `PhotoScan.alignChunks` with an empty first argument, while the documentation states that it expects a list of chunks.

You could initialize an empty list before your loop:

```
chunks = []
```

And add completed chunks to the list from inside the loop:

```
    # ...
    chunks.append(new_chunk)
```

Then call the function:

```
PhotoScan.alignChunks(chunks, chunk[0], ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and the result is : TypeError: reference chunk is specified but is not a Chunk object

Comment: This means that the second argument needs to be a Chunk. Try `PhotoScan.alignChunks(chunks, chunks[0], ...)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
PhotoScan.alignChunks(,1,method="points",accuracy='low', preselection=True)
                      ^
```

Before the ',' you need the chunks!

Comment: I know but what I don't know is hot to code it. The names of my chunks are 1 and 2. I tried [1,2], it doesn't work.
I bet there is a way to name the chunks in this software but i'm not able to find it. like [chunk(1),chunk(2)] something like that... but I can't find the good way

Comment: @julien, I don't write Python, but perhaps `main_doc.chunks`?